# CGSizeMake Doesn't Work for Constant

Tags: objective-c

Is there a way to do this type of thing?

```
static const CGSize maxPageSize = CGSizeMake(460, 651);
```

This is illegal because "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant."

I could use individual floats, of course, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since `CGSize` is just a simple C-struct:

```
struct CGSize {
  CGFloat width;
  CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

You can use an initializer list:

```
static const CGSize maxPageSize = {460, 651};
```

Comment: So couldn't I use that instead of `CGSizeMake` everywhere?

Comment: @Yar, yes you could. The argument against doing so is that it will break if Apple ever changes the internal layout of the struct.

Comment: Thanks, glad I asked that last bit too.

Comment: You can use _designated initializer:_ static const CGSize size = {.width = 100, .height = 200}. It will break only if Apple changes field names ('width' and 'height'), but in this case your code will probably break anyway :) Btw, it's also possible to use struct initializers in-place: [someObj doSmthWithSize:(CGSize){.width = 10, .height = 20}].

Answer (score 1):

```
CGSize
```

A structure that contains width and height values.

```
struct CGSize {
   CGFloat width;
   CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

**Fields**
width
A width value.
height
A height value.

```
const CGSize CGSizeZero;
```

e.g

```
static const CGSize pageSize = {320, 480};
```